# How do I collect rows from QItemSelection

Tags: python, pyqt, selection, pyside, qitemselectionmodel

What is the best way to collect a list of `QModelIndex` per row from a `QItemSelection`. Currently `QItemSelection` returns a list of `QModelIndex` for each row and each column. I only need it for each row.

Comment: How is the `QItemSelection` created?

Comment: It's accessed from this : selectionChanged(const QItemSelection & selected, const QItemSelection & deselected) which is triggered when a user makes a selection in a treeview.

Comment: QModelIndex is associated to an item of the model, neither rows nor columns are separated. So I do not understand what you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using a view where the selection behaviour is to select rows, the simplest method would be this:

```
def selected_rows(self, selection):
    indexes = []
    for index in selection.indexes():
        if index.column() == 0:
            indexes.append(index)
    return indexes
```

A somewhat shorter (but not much faster) alternative to the above would be:

```
from itertools import filterfalse

def selected_rows(self, selection):
    return list(filterfalse(QtCore.QModelIndex.column, selection.indexes()))
```

However, if the selection behaviour is to select items, you would need this:

```
def selected_rows(self, selection):
    seen = set()
    indexes = []
    model = self.tree.model()
    for index in selection.indexes():
        if index.row() not in seen:
            indexes.append(model.index(index.row(), 0))
            # or if you don't care about the specific column
            # indexes.append(index)
            seen.add(index.row())
    return indexes
```